# react-native-maps won't render nested elements for iOS

Tags: ios, google-maps, react-native, react-native-maps

I am using `react-native-maps` exclusively for my application. I have a lot of logic inside the map. There are markers, heatmaps (using the `react-native-heatmaps` package) and also polygons (using the `react-native-maps-directions` package).

Today I wanted to refactor my Map component therefore I broke down the functionality into 2 parts - Points and Roads my MapView had the following structure before the refactoring

```
<MapView>
    <Heatmap {Some props here} />
    {some function that will render a couple of Markers}
    {some function that will render a cople of MapViewDirections}
</MapView>
```

This used to work for both Android and iOS.

After the refactoring it started looking like that:

```
<MapView>
    <MyPointsComponent />
    <MyRoadsComponent />
</MapView>
```

This would work the same way in Android as before, however on iOS it won't display anything on the map.

I then tested the smallest example possible:

```
<MapView>
    <View>
        <Marker coordinates={{somecoordinates}} />
    </View>
</MapView>
```

This works on both iOS and Android

```
<MapView>
    <MyComponentThatReturnsAMArker />
</MapView>
```

This works for both iOS and Android independent from where the markers are loaded from.

```
<MapView>
    <View>
        <MyComponentThatReturnsAMArker />
    </View>
</MapView>
```

This works for both iOS and Android if markers are local - populated since the initial load of the map.

This does not work for iOS but works on Android if the markers are loaded dynamically from the backend hence populated later (not on initial load)

I am looking for any solutions in both directions:

1. Workaround to get it working, because I don't want to give up on the refactoring
2. I have the maps library forked so maybe I could change it to work in this scenario (I already have changes there related to it not supporting Heatmaps out of the box) [here](https://github.com/angelvenchev/react-native-maps)

P.S. I am using the Google Maps provider on iOS because of the Heatmaps and I cannot give up on it.